# SQ: Add custom Measure into custom plugin

Tags: java, sonarqube

I've implemented custom plugin and I tried to add CustomMetric and create my own Domain and it looks like:

```
    private Metric<Integer> PROVIDER_METRIC =
        metricBuilder("provider", "Count of providers", ValueType.INT)
                .setDescription("Number of Providers")
                .setDirection(Metric.DIRECTION_WORST)
                .setDomain("Custom Domain")
                .create();
```

During adding custom metric to SonarContext I've got the following exception:

```
[WARNING] Unable to analyse file: [..nameScanningFile]
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown metric: provider
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.DefaultSensorStorage.saveMeasure(DefaultSensorStorage.java:236)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.DefaultSensorStorage.store(DefaultSensorStorage.java:212)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.sensor.measure.internal.DefaultMeasure.doSave(DefaultMeasure.java:95)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.sensor.internal.DefaultStorable.save(DefaultStorable.java:45)
    at com.generic.impl.visitors.GenericMetricsVisitor.addMetric(GenericMetricsVisitor.java:42)
```

I've tried to use an existing domain (`Size`, for example) during creation new metric, but I've got the same error.
Does it mean that I dont't have right to create my own metric? Because when I update CoreMetrics (for example, `CoreMetrics.COMPLEXITY`) I saw them on UI. Or maybe I've done something wrong?